# What are requirements visiting Grodno (Hrodna) area in Belarus from Lithuania or Poland?

Tags: visas, belarus

Currently there is no visa requirement to visit Grodno area in Belarus.

- Is it valid only tourists? Can I visit it independently without
  buying tourist services?
- How long does it take to pass customs and cross the boarder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Old question, but some things have changed recently.)

**NO**. You can only visit Grodno(Hrodna) without a visa if you apply via a tourist operator. From [Grodno Visa Free](https://grodnovisafree.by/en/how-to-come.html):

> Foreign visitors can enter Belarus visa-free if they plan to visit the
> territory of a special tourist and recreational part “Avgustov
> Channel”, and its adjacent territories.
>
> One can enter Belarus through crossing Belarus State Border at the checkpoints Lesnaya (Rudavka),
> and Bruzgi (Kuznitsa Belostokskaya) which border on Poland; at the
> checkpoints Privalka (Shviandubre), and Privalka (Raigardas) which
> border on Lithuania.
>
> **01.01.2018** A checkpoint at the railway station in Grodno and at Grodno airport is included in the list of checkpoints that carry out
> visa-free entry.
>
> Visa free territories are:
>
> **01.01.2018** The Grodno region fully included into the territory of the park "Awgustow Canal".
>
> In order to enter the visa-free territory a
> foreign visitor should possess the document which is issued by
> Belarusian tourist agency.
>
> In order to obtain the document a foreign
> visitor is:
>
> - to address Belarusian travel agency which has the right to
>   issue such documents;
> - to receive confirmation approving a foreign
>   traveler's right to enter Belarus visa-free, and to obtain tourist
>   service which should be booked in advance.
>
> Before entering Belarus a
> foreign visitor is to get a health insurance for staying in Belarus.
>
> A foreign visitor entering Belarus visa-free is to present the following
> documents at Belarus State Border checkpoint:
>
> - a valid document which allows to cross State Borders of foreign countries (passport);
> - the document issued by Belarusian travel agency which allows to enter the
>   above mentioned territories visa-free;
> - Health insurance.
>
> A migration card is to be drawn up at the checkpoint of Belarus State Border.
>
> Comment: in case of migration card loss, a tourist will be fined.

So, it seems while you *may* be able to travel on your own once you're inside Belarus but you *must* buy the services to get there in the first place (and get the necessary documents). I suspect you may also run into issues if you don't actually use the booked service, so I would recommend arranging a custom itinerary with the operator (I would guess most of them are quite flexible).

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you can visit Belarus without any tourist vouchers. However, beware that this 5-day visa-free rule applies **only to air entry**.
2. But if you ask about ground entry (I assume so), it depends. Depends on load of border check-points and queues presence/absence. Even the Lord cannot predict it.

You can check *approximate* load [at the Border Committee website](http://gpk.gov.by/en/maps/).

For example, this snapshot of Lithuanian checkpoint Benayakoni shows us queue of 10 **trucks**.

[image]

Cars' lines **on entry** can be evaluated only [via CCTVs](http://gpk.gov.by/en/maps/ochered.php). Information is updated **bihourly**.

P.S. Official transcript is **Hrodna**.

Comment: So do ground entry require tourist vouchers?

Comment: It requires visa, which can be not only tourist visa but business visa, and others. Requirements vary by visa type.

Comment: AFAIK, you will need invitation from a person or letter of support from a tourist company or other recreational institution. [Source](http://mfa.gov.by/en/visa/typesofvisa/).